# Why is Rubygems still installing docs when I told it not to?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ri

I have this in my `~/.gemrc` file:

```
---
:backtrace: false
:benchmark: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- http://gems.github.com
- https://rubygems.org
- https://rails-assets.org
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
:gem: --no-document
```

It took *literally about 8 minutes* to install sinatra, because of the `ri` documentation.  (I have the clock time in my prompt, so I'm not just taking a wild guess.)  How can I fix this so that it actually obeys my `~/.gemrc` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the leading `:` from `:gem:`.

Comment: Removing the leading `:` turns the key from a symbol to a string after YAML parses the file. Unfortunately gem isn't consistent with the naming of the variables; Some are symbols and some are strings. http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/